# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameterized

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@user_code", SqlDbType.Char, 4)
    param.Value = "0016"
    Const sqlstr As String = "select sectors.sector_code,sector_name   from user_sectors inner join sectors on user_sectors.sector_code = sectors.sector_code  where user_code = @user_code  and sectors.sector_code not in ('z')"
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, _con)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_code")
    da.Fill(ds)
    ddl.DataValueField = "sector_code"
    ddl.DataTextField = "sector_name"
    ddl.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    ddl.DataBind()    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not phrased as a question, just a statement, we have to guess what you want.

Comment: see my answer to do whole parameter instantiation in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess line

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_code")
```

should be

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because its a [`SqlParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx) and not a `string` collection.

If you call the appropriate [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x.aspx) overload it will however make the instance for you, if given enough information.

Like this perhaps,

```
Dim newParam = da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_code", sqlDbType.Char, 4)
newParam.Value = "0016"
```

or, replace several lines like this

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add( _
    New SqlParameter("@user_code", SqlDbType.Char, 4) With { .Value = "0016" }))
```

or, if you want to use many lines, just add

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `param` in `add`

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param)
```